# Powershell > Get-Counter - CookedValue too high

Tags: powershell, counter, perfmon

I'm trying since few weeks to get CPU Stats from differents Windows server, with PowerShell.
I've try the following :

```
$DataCPU = (Get-Counter $Counter -MaxSamples 20 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).countersamples
```

OR

```
$Data = @()
$Data1 = (Get-Counter $Counter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).countersamples
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$Data2 = (Get-Counter $Counter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).countersamples 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$Data3 = (Get-Counter $Counter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).countersamples
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$Data4 = (Get-Counter $Counter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).countersamples
$DataCPU = $Data + $Data1 + $Data2 + $Data3 + $Data4
```

On both, i'm facing on different servers, strange value, like :

> ```
>     "Path":  "\\\\xxx-xxxxx\\process(chrome#91)\\% processor time",
>     "InstanceName":  "chrome",
>     "CookedValue":  1353.6754699664537,
>     "RawValue":  152656250,
>     "SecondValue":  132475929754152508,
>     "MultipleCount":  1,
>     "CounterType":  542180608,
>     "Timestamp":  "\/Date(1603119375415)\/",
>     "Timestamp100NSec":  132476001754150000,
>     "Status":  0,
>     "DefaultScale":  0,
>     "TimeBase":  10000000
> ```

Server has 4 VCpu, value should not be more than 400 ?